# debugging a ros Python program

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I have a python program which I run with rosrun

```
rosrun  node_example pytalker.py
```

I want to debug this program
I know that there is a tool called pdb used for debuging, but I don't know how to use it with rosrun.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272279/debugging-a-ros-python-program/) by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

noob, but afaik, rosrun just eliminates the need to go to the directory with the file in it.
You can thus easily get around using rosrun by going to the "node_example" package manually, eg with "roscd node_example". There you should find the pytalker.py file, that you can start with pdb.

---

Originally posted by [Alberth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32151/alberth/) with karma: 91 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-05**:
This will work, but `rosrun` (and `roslaunch`) does a little more than just `cd $pkg && ./node_script`: it also provides the node with its name, location of the logfile, private parameters (optional) and (topic) remappings.

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-10-05**:
It is working for me with `rosrun  node_example pytalker.py`   by adding import pdb and pdb.set_trace().
But, the program doen't stop in the breakpoint. It continues to run the callback functions ?

**Comment by [Alberth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32151/alberth/) on 2017-10-09**:
Never tried that, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828956/pdb-cannot-break-in-another-thread suggests to add a set_trace in each thread. In any case, this would be a generic pdb-threading problem, rather than a ROS-specific problem. You might find better help in a generic Python forum/site.

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-09**:
How about just [rospy.loginfo('Some text or variable')](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Logging)?

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2017-10-09**:
It works for me when adding pdb.set_trace() at the beginning of each method I want to debug.